# How to upload an image to a specific folder on cloudiary with laravel jrm2k6/cloudder

Tags: laravel, cloudinary

I want to crop the avatar image and upload that on a specific folder of cloudiary using Laravel jrm2k6/cloudder but faced to a error to upload an image.
Can anyone help me what's wrong or show how to solve?

Following is the error message stored on a log file.

```
[2019-10-20 10:39:38] local.ERROR: Invalid Signature 22800853dcbe6c9972b65d99946460f1965a6e06. String to sign - 'folder=media/users/1/avatar&timestamp=
1571535576'. {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Cloudinary\\Error(code: 401): Invalid Signature 22800853dcbe6c9972b65d99946460f1965a6e06. String to sig
n - 'folder=media/users/1/avatar&timestamp=1571535576'. at /Users/kondonator/Development/tiny-services/vendor/cloudinary/cloudinary_php/src/Uploader.ph
p:515)
[stacktrace]
#0 /Users/kondonator/Development/tiny-services/vendor/cloudinary/cloudinary_php/src/Uploader.php(374): Cloudinary\\Uploader::call_api('upload', Array,
Array, '/private/var/tm...')
#1 /Users/kondonator/Development/tiny-services/vendor/cloudinary/cloudinary_php/src/Uploader.php(99): Cloudinary\\Uploader::call_cacheable_api('upload'
, Array, Array, '/private/var/tm...')
#2 /Users/kondonator/Development/tiny-services/vendor/jrm2k6/cloudder/src/JD/Cloudder/CloudinaryWrapper.php(122): Cloudinary\\Uploader::upload('/privat
e/var/tm...', Array)
#3 /Users/kondonator/Development/tiny-services/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(239): JD\\Cloudder\\CloudinaryWrapper
->upload('/private/var/tm...', NULL, Array, Array)
#4 /Users/kondonator/Development/tiny-services/app/Http/Controllers/UserController.php(150): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::__callStatic('upload
', Array)
#5 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\\UserController->update(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), '1')
```

And the following is the code of UserController.php.

```
  $path = $request->file('avatar')
                  ->getRealPath();

  $image = Image::make($path);

  $image->crop($request->width, $request->height, $request->x, $request->y)
        ->resize(200, 200)
        ->save();

  $folder = 'media/users/'.$id.'/avatar';

  Cloudder::upload($path, null, ['folder' => $folder], []);

  $result = Cloudder::getResult();

  $avatar = Cloudder::getPublicId();
```

The last is the part of .env those are from Cloudinary's Dashboard -> Account Details.

```
CLOUDINARY_API_KEY=XXXXX
CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET=YYYYY
CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME=ZZZZZ
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The string (`folder=media/users/1/avatar&timestamp=1571535576`) prior to the `api_secret` being concatanated at the end is correct, but the signature it should've produced is `083dc25c1d1e4a90f84336450f21c9fb59b343f5`.

I suggest double-checking the `CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET` in your configuration (.env) and if you've made any changes to it then you should restart your server so they take effect.

What you can also do is manually generate the correct signature on the command line just to double-check with the one that's being thrown as part of the exception. Replace `<API_SECRET>` with your actual one in the command below:

```
echo -n "folder=media/users/1/avatar&timestamp=1571535576<API_SECRET>" | sha1sum
```

Also, not related to the error, but I would recommend keeping your cloud name in all lowercase in your configuration. The API responses would return `url` and `secure_url` with it in all lowercase and also that's the case for using the URLs that are generated by the Media Library. Requesting resources with different casing would result in different cache-keys at the CDN.

Comment: Following to your feedback, I did the following but I still could not solve the problem.   
First, I double-checked the lines in .env and found they are correct.    
Second, I calculated the signature by myself based on your formula on my MacOS.  
As a result, the signature the browser showed and that I calculated on my MacOS were not same. I also tried some algorithms as 1 (default), 224, 256, 384, 512, 512224, 512256 but never same.    
Third, I forgot to mention the version of laravel. It's 6.3.0.    
Do you have any additional advices?  
Thanks in advance again.

Comment: I would suggest also checking your system's environment variables in case there is one called CLOUDINARY_URL or any other CLOUDINARY_ ones which will overwrite any other credentials set in the config. In addition, I suggest adding some debugging code to print out the values that are being signed inside the api_sign_request( ) method of Cloudinary\HttpClient; That will tell you the actual value of the string (including API Secret) that is being signed and could help in narrowing this down.

Comment: I have changed the code again and again and finally it worked.  
The code is like this:  
`      Cloudder::upload($path, null, ['folder' => $folder, 'overwrite' => TRUE, 'resource_type' => 'image']);` . 
Thank you for your advices.